# How to separate the outputs with commas? How can I improve this code to look more decent?

Tags: c++, function

So after learning some Python, I decided to check out C++ and give it a try and decided to try and code Collatz Conjecture in Xcode.

Here's what I got.

```
#include <iostream>

int collatz() {
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    int x = 0;
    std::cin >> x;
    while (x != 1) {
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            x /= 2;
            std::cout << x << " ";
        } else {
            x = (3 * x) + 1;
            std::cout << x << " ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    collatz();
}
```

Extra Question: In Python there is condition called elif, how is it called in C++?

Comment: Extra answer: `else if`

Comment: Separate with commas: `std::cout << x << " ";` -> `std::cout << x << ",";`

Comment: I know but what about the comma at the end

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int collatz() {
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    while (x != 1) {
        x = x % 2 ? x / 2 : x * 3 + 1;
        std::cout << x << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << "\b\b  \b\b" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    collatz();
}
```

Comment: Your condition is reversed. You divide by 2 when `x` is odd, and multiply when it's even.

Comment: I was looking for no comma at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this if you don't want comma at last 
Add a check not to add comma for last digit

```
#include <iostream>

int collatz() {
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    int x = 0;
    std::cin >> x;
    while (x != 1) {
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            x /= 2;
            std::cout << x ;
        } else {
            x = (3 * x) + 1;
            std::cout << x ;
        }
        if (x!=1)
        std::cout<<",";
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    collatz();
}
```

Output

```
Enter a number: 5
16,8,4,2,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your original code (I see you've edited it), you can do this if you want to avoid an extra conditional and multiple calls through `cout` in your loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int collatz()
{
  std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
  int x = 0;
  std::cin >> x;
  std::string output;
  while (x != 1)
  {
    if (x % 2 == 0)
    {
      x /= 2;
      output += std::to_string(x) + ", ";
    }
    else
    {
      x = (3 * x) + 1;
      output += std::to_string(x) + ", ";
    }
  }
  output.replace(output.rfind(',', output.length()), 2, "");
  std::cout << output.c_str();
  return 0;
}
```

Probably the only thing that needs explaining here is `output.replace()`.  `rfind()` finds the last comma, starting at the end.  `replace` then clobbers the two characters at that position (", ").